# Como criar uma Animação no JavaScript usando For

Tags: javascript, funções, script, for, animação

Estou tentando fazer uma `<div>` ter o background alterado para as três cores primarias, no caso **Yellow**, **Blue** e **Red**, porem só começaria a alterar a cor 4 segundos depois da pagina ser atualizada, escrevi uma função que é chamada 4 segundos depois da pagina atualizar, porem as cores não mudam, na verdade ele ignora as primeiras cores e pula direto para a ultima, e não ocorre o efeito de animação, simplesmente fica vermelho, segue a baixo o código...

```
<script>
    var d = window.document.querySelector('div#msg');

    setTimeout(mudarCor, 4000);


    function mudarCor(){  
        var contador =0;
        while(contador <= 9){

            d.style.background = 'yellow';
            
            d.style.background = 'blue';
            
            d.style.background = 'red';
            contador +=1;
        }
     }
    
</script>
```

Eu quero que altere entre as 3 cores, que mostre as cores mudando na tela, mas necessito que seja com a estrutura de repetição for ou while, porquê talvez eu precise deixar isso rodando infinitamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazer animação em Javascript, com navegadores modernos, deve-se usar o método [`window.requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame) que informa ao navegador que deseja-se realizar uma animação e pede ao navegador que chame uma função específica para atualizar um quadro de animação antes da próxima repintura.

O método tem como argumento uma callback que será invocado antes da repintura. Por sua vez o callback possui um único argumento um [`DOMHighResTimeStamp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp), que indica o momento no qual o callback foi enfileirado por `requestAnimationFrame()`.

O número de callbacks invocados está normalmente na ordem de 60 chamadas por segundo, mas normalmente acompanha-se a taxa de atualização do display na maioria dos navegadores, como recomenda a W3C.

Nesse exemplo é criada uma animação que inicia após 4s e vai trocando as cores de um `<div>`.

```js
var inicio = null; //inicio da animação
var cores = ['yellow', 'blue', 'red']; //Array de cores 
let elem = document.getElementById("colorido");

requestAnimationFrame(mudarCor);

function mudarCor(tempo) {

  if (!inicio) inicio = tempo;

  // Aguarda 4s antes de iniciar a animação
  if ((tempo - inicio) > 4000) {
    //Escolhe uma cor "aleatoriamente" e muda a atual
    elem.style.background = cores[Math.floor(Math.random() * cores.length)];
  }

  //Faz a requisição do próximo quadro
  requestAnimationFrame(mudarCor);
}
```

```css
#colorido {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<h4>Aviso!!!</h4><span>Se você sofre com epilepsia ou fotossensibilidade não veja esse exemplo</span>
<div id="colorido"></div>
```

Se quiser um efeito menos intenso basta fazer as mudanças em uma frequência menor

```js
var inicio = null; //inicio da animação
var ultima = null; // momento da última atualização
var cores = ['yellow', 'blue', 'red']; //Array de cores 
let elem = document.getElementById("colorido");

requestAnimationFrame(mudarCor);

function mudarCor(tempo) {

  if (!inicio) {
    inicio = tempo;
    ultima = tempo;
  }

  // Aguarda 4s antes de iniciar a animação
  if ((tempo - inicio) > 4000) {
    // Só troca a cor a cada 0,5s
    if (tempo - ultima > 500) {
      //Escolhe uma cor "aleatoriamente" e muda a atual
      elem.style.background = cores[Math.floor(Math.random() * cores.length)];
      ultima = tempo;
    }

  }

  //Faz a requisição do próximo quadro
  requestAnimationFrame(mudarCor);
}
```

```css
#colorido {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<h4>Aviso!!!</h4><span>Se você sofre com epilepsia ou fotossensibilidade não veja esse exemplo</span>
<div id="colorido"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nessa caso, para a cor ser alterada dentro de um intervalo de tempo, o ideal é utilizar o **setInterval()** em vez do **setTimeout()**, pois ele será executado repetidamente.

Exemplo usando o **setInterval()**:

```
<script>
    var d = window.document.querySelector('div#msg');
    var arrayCores = ['yellow','blue','red'];
    var corAtual = -1;

    function mudarCor() {
        corAtual = (corAtual < arrayCores.length ? (corAtual + 1) : 0);

        d.style.background = arrayCores[corAtual];
    }

    setInterval(mudarCor, 4000);
</script>
```